# Why Won't Rhythmbox Coverart Plug-in Work? (Kubuntu)

Tags: kubuntu, rhythmbox, plugins

I recently switched to Ubuntu and then this morning to Kubuntu. I really love Kubuntu, I want to run this as the only OS on my Macbook but there's one issue that I just can't fix.

So I've installed Rhythmbox and then went to install the Coverart plugins with these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fossfreedom/rhythmbox-plugins
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rhythmbox-plugin-coverart-browser
```

Then I open up Rhythmbox, click tools and click plug-ins. The plugin is listed but when I double click it to mark the checkbox it adds a little red horizontal line in a circle next to it instead and doesn't activate. The "CoverArt Browser Search Providers" plug-in that it requires works fine though. If anyone could help me out with this I'll be very happy!

Here is what I get when I type "rhythmbox" in Terminal (Konsole):

```
(rhythmbox:3110): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2158, in _find_spec
AttributeError: 'DynamicImporter' object has no attribute 'find_spec'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/reece/.local/share/rhythmbox/plugins/coverart_browser/coverart_browser.py", line 32, in <module>
    from coverart_browser_source import CoverArtBrowserSource
  File "/home/reece/.local/share/rhythmbox/plugins/coverart_browser/coverart_browser_source.py", line 37, in <module>
    from coverart_widgets import PanedCollapsible
  File "/home/reece/.local/share/rhythmbox/plugins/coverart_browser/coverart_widgets.py", line 26, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Notify
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/importer.py", line 144, in find_module
    'introspection typelib not found' % namespace)
ImportError: cannot import name Notify, introspection typelib not found

(rhythmbox:3110): libpeas-WARNING **: Error loading plugin 'coverart_browser'

(rhythmbox:3110): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Add to Playlist


(rhythmbox:3110): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Add to Playlist


(rhythmbox:3110): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Add to Playlist


(rhythmbox:3110): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Add to Playlist


(rhythmbox:3110): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Add to Playlist


(rhythmbox:3110): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Add to Playlist


(rhythmbox:3110): Rhythmbox-WARNING **: Unable to grab media player keys: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon was not provided by any .service files
```

Comment: type rhythmbox in a terminal and add to your question the output you see in the terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important part of your output when you ran rhythmbox from a terminal is this bit:

> ImportError: cannot import name Notify, introspection typelib not found

What this means is that Kubuntu does not have the following package installed by default - gir1.2-notify-0.7

To install this package:

```
sudo apt-get install gir1.2-notify-0.7
```

---

As an aside - since the Debian package is provided by myself ... I'll updated this package at the next release to include this dependency.

Comment: Thank you so much, for your time, answer and support. This has fixed my issue! Please do that, for people (like me) switching from OS X who are used to an album view, the coverart plugin is a huge nicety.