# Why Won't Rhythmbox Coverart Plug-in Work? (Lubuntu 32 bits )

Tags: lubuntu, 32-bit, rhythmbox, plugins

I have a similar question to the one asked here : [Why Won't Rhythmbox Coverart Plug-in Work? (Kubuntu)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/719136/why-wont-rhythmbox-coverart-plug-in-work-kubuntu)

I am running a Lubuntu 16.04 32 bits OS on my old laptop that I want to use as a "mediacenter/tagger". I am using Rhythmbox on my other regular Ubuntu desktop with the Covert Art plugin with no issues, however, I was not able to activate the Covert Art plugin this time on "Lubuntu 32 bits". Here is my standard Rhythmbox install (and whole plugins install).

```
sudo apt-get install rhythmbox
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fossfreedom/rhythmbox-plugins
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rhythmbox-plugin-complete
```

Rhythmbox then launches nicely, and so on. I am able to active the covertart-search plugin (required by covertart-browser) but when I tried to activate the Covert Art browser, I get a "unable to load plugin" sort of message with an exclamation mark.

I then ran Rhythmbox from the command line using a terminal and here are the full logs

```
famille@jukebox:~$ rhythmbox

** (rhythmbox:4720): WARNING **: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files

(rhythmbox:4720): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
/usr/lib/rhythmbox/plugins/coverart_browser/coverart_widgets.py:26: PyGIWarning: Notify was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Notify', '0.7') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Notify
/usr/lib/rhythmbox/plugins/coverart_browser/coverart_covericonview.py:28: PyGIWarning: PangoCairo was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('PangoCairo', '1.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import PangoCairo

(rhythmbox:4720): libpeas-WARNING **: Error importing plugin 'coverart_browser':
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 890, in _find_spec
AttributeError: 'DynamicImporter' object has no attribute 'find_spec'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 662, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/lib/rhythmbox/plugins/coverart_browser/coverart_browser.py", line 32, in <module>
    from coverart_browser_source import CoverArtBrowserSource
  File "/usr/lib/rhythmbox/plugins/coverart_browser/coverart_browser_source.py", line 49, in <module>
    from coverart_artistinfo import ArtistInfoPane
  File "/usr/lib/rhythmbox/plugins/coverart_browser/coverart_artistinfo.py", line 28, in <module>
    from gi.repository import WebKit
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/importer.py", line 127, in find_module
    'introspection typelib not found' % namespace)
ImportError: cannot import name WebKit, introspection typelib not found

(rhythmbox:4720): libpeas-WARNING **: Error loading plugin 'coverart_browser'

(rhythmbox:4720): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Ajouter à la liste de lecture


(rhythmbox:4720): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Ajouter à la liste de lecture


(rhythmbox:4720): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Ajouter à la liste de lecture


(rhythmbox:4720): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Ajouter à la liste de lecture
```

I have two WARNINGS and an ERROR but seems that the important part is the ERROR message

```
ImportError: cannot import name WebKit, introspection typelib not found
```

I have checked WebKit package

```
gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 is already the newest version (2.10.9-1ubuntu1).
```

So I tried using another webkit package

```
sudo apt-get install gir1.2-webkit-3.0:i386
```

At this point Covert Art Browser plugin is loaded but when I click on the interface to use it I get a not so nice (segmentation fault) core dumped

```
(rhythmbox:5475): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_box_reorder_child: assertion 'old_link != NULL' failed
Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)
```

Any help here would be appreciated.
Thanks

**EDIT** : looks like it is something similar to that issue here : https://github.com/fossfreedom/coverart-browser/issues/382

So, WebKit and 32 bits don't like each other it seems